# How to change current date underline color react-dateRangePicker

Tags: reactjs, class, overriding, react-date-range

i want to change the color of current date underline in react.js

i have tried the custom classes its not working to override i want a syntax to over ride react date range picker classes. i have used rangesColors but unable to get the syntax which let me to customize the design

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rangecolors` property which is an array of strings(hex color codes).

refer https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-date-range